# ServerBootstrap bind method

Tags: java, netty

I am using Netty 4.0.33 lib.
Would tell me the meaning for ServerBootstrap.bind() method?
Is it bind all local IP address and TCP port?

How about the ServerBootstrap.bind(int inetPort) method mean?
Is it create a channel for all local IP address and inetPort and then bind on it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ServerBootstrap.bind() will bind a new Channel to the localAddress you have fed the Serverboostrap using its ServerBootstrap.localAddress(...) method. If you haven't fed it with localAddress - calling to ServerBootstrap.bind() will throw IllegalStateException("localAddress not set").

ServerBootstrap.bind(int inetPort) will bind a new Channel to the wildcard address and the specified port number. Meaning it will bind on port inetPort for any IP address on your host.